Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload while adding properties
I am trying to use an App script to add properties to the files which lie in a shared Drive.
By using Following Code:
addCustomProperties(fileID, Customer_name, Process_Type, Priority);

function addCustomProperties(fileID, customerName, processType, Priority) {
  var resource = {
    properties: {
      CustomerName: customerName,
      ProcessType: processType,
      Priority: Priority,
    }
  };
  Drive.Files.update(resource, fileID, {supportsAllDrives: true});
}

I've already enabled the advanced google API, and I am pretty sure the file ID is correct. But I still got following error message:
Exception: The mediaData parameter only supports Blob types for upload.

Anyone know a possible solution for this?
Appreciate
I am trying to solve this problem and add custom properties to the file which lies in shared Drive.

I somehow fixed it. Replace Drive.Files.update(resource, fileID, {supportsAllDrives: true});
by Drive.Files.update(resource,fileID, null,{ supportsAllDrives: true },);

helped me too! Please add it as an answer!
